# cannot access NPOIFSFileSystem

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I want to read xls and xlsx files.

I use this line to access my workbook.

```
myWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

My build gradle looks like this:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.application"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/poi-3.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar')
    compile project(':aFileChooser')
}
```

I cannot compile my project as I get the following error:

> Error:(210, 41) error: cannot access NPOIFSFileSystem
>   class file for org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem not found
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly these lines:

```
compile files('libs/poi-3.7.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar')
```

Specifically, two issues. Firstly, you *must* use matching versions of the Apache POI jars. It is not supported to use a mixture of old and new jars at the same time, they must all be from the same release. Secondly, both your jars are old ones, which due to their age miss some features.

Switch those to both be from POI 3.10.1 (or newer, eg 3.11 beta 2 as of writing), and you should then have the classes you need